# How to keep Json.Encode/Decode from converting characters into chinese letters in C#?

Tags: c#, json, encoding, decoding, chinese-locale

so first off, i know next to nothing about encoding, so thats probably the problem.
What I'm trying to do is Decode and Encode a String with Json.Decode and Json.Encode. So in the end, there should be the same string as before.
So a part of my target string has the following values in it : 
"\":\"\u6b22\u8fce\u6765\u5230\" etc you get the idea. So now i convert the String like this:

```
DynamicJsonObject jsonObject = Json.Decode(Raw);
String newRaw = Json.Encode(jsonObject);
```

Now newRaw should be the same as Raw, am i right? Well the characters i mentioned look like this in newRaw:

欢迎来到《奇异人生：暴风前夕》。要及时获得最新

How can i fix that? I know that Raw has UTF8 encoding, but converting newRaw to UTF8 did not help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you printing `newRaw`? Keep in mind that if you do `Console.WriteLine("\u6b22")` you will print out 欢, not the literal string `\u6b22`

Answer (score 0):

`"\u6b22"` is a string constant that contains a single character: the [unicode codepoint 6b22](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=6b22&useutf8=false), a simplified Chinese character. This isn't a question of Json, but a question of c# string escape sequences.